# Is thеrе any wаy tо propеrly displаy nеgativе timе spаns in Exсеl?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

Is there any way to make Excel show a negative time span? If I subtract two time values (say, when subtracting the actual amount of time spent on something from the amount of time planned for it) and the result is negative, Excel just fills the result cell with hashes to notify me that the result cannot be displayed as a time value. Even OpenOffice.org Calc and Google Spreadsheets can display negative time values.

Is there a way to work around that issue by using conditional formatting? I really don't want to create some workaround by calculating the hours and minutes myself or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

To display negative time values, change the Excel default date system:

- Click the *File* tab and select *Options*
- On the Excel Options dialog, click *Advanced*
- Under "When calculating this workbook", check "Use 1904 data system"
- Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that any existing dates in that workbook will then be 4 years later than you first entered them and you will need to change all dates previously entered.